# Does Windows use UPnP to open/forward ports by default?

Tags: windows, networking, router, port-forwarding

I've heard a claim that says that Windows (or Windows firewall) uses UPnP to open/forward ports.

I'm aware of the possibility of configuring routers which support this via UPnP (e.g [this one](http://upnp-portmapper.sourceforge.net/)), but I was unable to find any clear reference on whether and under what conditions Windows does so (msdn or otherwise), except for [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/922.windows-home-server-router-setup.aspx#UPnP_Router_Configuration) indirect reference.

So what I'd like to know is when, if at all, Windows would attempt using UPnP for configuring the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows *itself* doesn't use UPnP for setting up port forwarding because it has no built-in services that should be globally accessible. (Indeed even the firewall defaults to limiting them to the local subnet.)

Normally this is done by individual programs which include their own UPnP and/or NAT-PMP client libraries. BitTorrent clients would be a common example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you maybe have an msdn (or other) article that explains that in more detail ? (And one which I can qoute)